# What is remote_tmp in ansible used for?

Tags: ansible

I'm learning ansible config recently and encountered with this variable `remote_tmp`. What does the tmp folder do?
Does this folder hold all the ansible folder contents from my manage node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm gonna answer my question here. Ansible works by transferring modules to your remote machines, running them, and then cleaning up after itself. This setting allower user change the temp folder ansible is using on remote machine.